# VertX Service Proxy in Java 11 throws TimeTrackingProcessor warning

Tags: java, gradle, vert.x, java-11

Wondering if anyone has come across this before.. I have a really simple VertX service that I'm generating a proxy for. Relevant parts of my build config;

```
plugins {
  id "io.dotinc.vertx-codegen-plugin" version "0.1.0"
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.11'

dependencies {
  implementation "io.vertx:vertx-core:3.8.4"
  ...
}

codeGen {
  generatedDirs = "src/main/generated"
  generationPath = "proxy"
}
```

When I set `sourceCompatibility` to `1.8`, everything works fine. When I try to use Java 11, I get an odd gradle warning;

`warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_8' from annotation processor 'org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.TimeTrackingProcessor' less than -source '11'`

Everything appears to still run and function normally, but I'm wondering if this is indicative of an issue. Has anyone come across this before? Is there a fix or is this safe to ignore?

Comment: I've come across this warning as well in the process of using service proxies, doesn't seem to affect anything. From what I can tell, the classes in `gradle/subprojects/language-java/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/compile/processing`, where `TimeTrackingProcessor` is located, do not support Java 9 modules, so they probably have them configured to return SourceVersion.RELEASE_8